# Graphics Card Power Draw

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

When researching graphics cards,  on every details page for the card there is a reccomended PSU wattage. (I.e. 500w). Is that including all the other componemts to run the whole system or is that just the gpu's by itself power draw?

Comment: I would say it is including all components (in an average setup), but some graphics boards do state the *actual* power draw, rather than the recommended PSU. [This](http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp) might be of value in the former case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics card and PSU requirement](http://superuser.com/questions/1035218/graphics-card-and-psu-requirement)

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation is a minimum for a "typical" system.  Every graphics card I've ever checked has had the actual draw from the card listed on the manufacturer's site, as well, so that you know what's "left over".

Answer (score 0):

That's recommended PSU for a basic setup with that GPU. IE not another 10 hard drives, or SLI configuration etc.  You can google 'psu calculator'.  This facility will help you to determine what your requirements are in terms of a psu.

Comment: You know... I didn't write an answer because I couldn't source my statement. For you to write almost the same thing I did in comment, please show some effort :) (or at least give me a millimeter of credit)